# Can I add an event to an object before it is created?

Tags: jquery

I have the following that is created dynamically:

```
<a class="editLink" href="/location/Edit?city=05">Edit</a>
```

This and other editLink rows are created dynamically.

What I would like to do is add some jQuery to these:

```
$(".editLink").button();
$(".editLink").click(function () {
    alert('edit link');
    return false;
});
```

Is there some way I can assign this BEFORE the elements appear? Also how can I deal with the following:

```
$(".editLink").button();
```

When the .editLink is not already there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use event delegation, by putting the handler on the document.

```
$(document).on('click', '.editLink', function() {
  alert('edit link');
  return false;
});
```

This is called "live" or "delegated" events.  The `$(document)` part identifies the element that will handle the event, this one must exist when this code is run.  You should set this to a parent element as far down as you can.  Using `document` is a bit overzealous, but it will work.

The `'.editLink'` string identifies a selector for any child elements inside the element with the handler.  When the event happens the original element is checked against this selector to see if something matching fired the event.  And if so, then run the event handler.

See working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/Squeegy/guz9A/1/

Note how the links are not present when the handler is bound, but they still trigger the handler when they are added later on.

Comment: Thanks Alex. How can I also deal with the - $(".editLink").button();  Is there some way of also doing this with "on" ?

Comment: That is not a standard jQuery method, I have no idea what it does or why you need it, so can't advise much there...

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Button is a jQuery UI method.

Comment: I'm not sure what it does, but this only works for event handlers.  If this method somehow transforms a link into a button, then the element probably needs to exist when it's run.  In which case you will have to call it after each link is inserted.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [jQuery.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method to listen for new elements on your page. When it added to page, the events added automatically.

Answer (score 3):

yeah you can do that by `deligating` the event using `on` inf you using jquery 1.7 or more else use `delegate`.

```
$('body').on('click', '.editLink', function() {
  alert('edit link');
  return false;
});
```

instead of body you can use any context selector(probably parent element) if you know to increase the performance

Answer (score 2):

you can use jquery delegate to it - http://api.jquery.com/delegate/